# Calling Jquery function from code behind and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

First I'll explain my senario:

I have a page in which users login or register. The login control and the register textbox are in two different divs and I use jQuery to hide one and show another.

Then in `register` div I have a `ScriptManager` and an `UpdatePanel` and inside it's content template I have my button called `check`, which checks that the given username is not already chosen. (I have it in there because I don't want a postback).

Now I want to code this:

When the button event check the username after it should call a jQuery function to show me the div in which all my other textboxes are contained.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ide = $("#reg");
    var log = $("#login");
    var reg = $("#register");
    var regfull = $("#regfull");
    reg.hide();
    regfull.hide();

    ide.click(function () {
        log.fadeOut().delay(1000);
        reg.show("slow");
    });
    function completereg() {
        regfull.show();
    }
});
```

This is my jQuery and I want to call the `completereg();` from code behind button onclick event and my button is in `UpdatePanel`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to move your function outside of the `$(document).ready()` block :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ide = $("#reg");
    var log = $("#login");
    var reg = $("#register");
    var regfull = $("#regfull");
    reg.hide();
    regfull.hide();

    ide.click(function () {
        log.fadeOut().delay(1000);
        reg.show("slow");
    });
});

function completereg() {
    $("#regfull").show();
}
```

Then add the following into the `$(document).ready()` block to listen for clicks and execute the `completereg` function :

```
$(document).on('click','#idofbutton',function(event) {
    completereg();
});
```

What the on function does is listen for clicks on the target (`document`) and checks the id (`#idofbutton`) of the trigger and performs the funciton ... this works for elements not yet added to the DOM. [Documentation for on() here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

The target, in this case `document`, should be a parent element of the trigger element - this should really be a containaing div.

Comment: hi thanks but there is the thing ... when i jit the button which is type ajax and so there is no document.ready that why my methord of passing my code into a litral is not working now how i can get jquery to work when there is no document.ready event happening ?

Comment: @user1105338 please add your HTML to you question and add all of your javascript or better create a http://jsfiddle.net/